# How to call a Java method with an explicit type parameter without specifying the class?

Tags: java, generics

The following code does not compile, because Java cannot infer the type parameter to getSomething:

```
class Example {
  static void callIt() {
    takeString(getSomething());
  }

  static void takeString(String s) {
  }

  static <T> T getSomething() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Is there some way to specify the type parameter like `<String>getSomething()`, but without specifying the name of the class it is being called on? i.e. not `Example.<String>getSomething()`.

Comment: It compiles in Java 8 and works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some way to specify the type parameter like
>   `<String>getSomething()`, but without specifying the name of the class
>   it is being called on? i.e. not `Example.<String>getSomething()`

No, there is not. [That is the syntax for explicitly providing a type argument to a generic method.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

Your code should compile on Java 8, with its improved and targeted type inference.

Comment: Was just going to mention the fact about Java 8. I had no trouble compiling his example.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just do :

```
static Object getSomething() {return null;}
```

then cast it to a string :

```
takeString((String)getSomething());
```

From your short example it's unclear why you need generics

Comment: The example was just a minimal example to explain the issue. The real code I am writing is using Mockito matchers, which are usually used with static imports for readability. I found myself having to write

    `when(mockServer.getSomething(Matchers.<List<MyId>>any()).thenReturn(DATA)`

which seems overly verbose.